# UV scaling not updating the texture in the object

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor

In the UV editing tab when I rescale and move the UV, the texture is not updating.
In the all other objects rescaling is working

[image]

[image]

Comment: It looks like this object is using a different material altogether, using something other than UV in the texture coordinate node. Kindly share a screenshot of your material setups.

Comment: I am sharing the ScreenShot of the shader editor. All objects are using the same wood material. I can rescale the UV to get proper scaling of texture on the other objects. but that one object is not updating

Comment: could you pls share your file?

Answer (score 1):

Reset the UV to the default in your UV editor on all objects. Now, go to your material, add a texture coordinate with a mapping node (which can automatically be done if you press Ctrl + Shift + T with the node wrangler addon on) and connect the mapping node's vector output to the vector of each of your textures.   plug the UV output of the texture coordinate into the mapping node's vector input, and now you can control the size/rotation of your material on every object altogether, removing any worry of manually editing the UVs.